# Swapping matrix rows with basic row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The basic row operations on a matrix include adding a multiple of one row to another row and multiplying a row by a nonzero number.

How can I use a sequence of just these operations to swap the rows of this matrix like so:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 a & b \\
    c & d
\end{pmatrix} \to 
\begin{pmatrix}
 c & d \\
    a & b
\end{pmatrix}\ ?$$

Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Row-swapping is usually included as another row-operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: add -1 times row 1 to row 2, then add row 2 to row 1. Can u take it from here?

Comment: The interchange operation can be written in terms of the other two elementary row operations. How can I conclude that "**interchanging two rows can be effected by elementary row operations of the other two types**" from this?

Comment: @zaira please Google "how to swap two variables without auxiliary spaces".